# How can I export a Photoshop DVD Menu (Widescreen) into Acrobat without distortion?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, export

I created a DVD Menu Design and need to export each page as a .pdf. When I do so the design is distorted horizontally. Specifically, it isn't as wide as the canvas is in Photoshop.

The results are the same if I export to .jpg. If I export to .png it is correct, however converting the pages to .pdf reproduces the issue.

D1/DV NTSC Widescreen(1.21) with Pixel Aspect Ratio Correction -> On.

In what ways can I fix the issue? I would prefer not to have to redesign if possible.

Comment: PDFs are for print media or self-contained documents and generally not for DVD menus. You actually *want* png files for menus. Why are you using PDF and JPG at all? If you want a PDF, you need to disable the Pixel Aspect Ratio (set it to square) and size the document for the widescreen rather than relying on the Pixel Aspect to do it for you.

Comment: Note, you can also save as PNG then use Acrobat to make a PDF of those PNG files. No alteration will occur then.

Comment: I only need to export the image to go in a .pdf version of my portfolio. I realize it won't be interactive. It's the design that matters.

Comment: When I convert the .png into a .pdf the issue is reproduced unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this with screen grabs from documentaries that were featured in some books I was designing. There were three books, with about 30-50 of these per book, and they were all square-pixel TIFs from non-square video frames, so I built the solution into an Action to save me the tedium of doing every one by hand. You should do the same if you're going to be running into this situation regularly.

When you create your DVD menu jpegs, you essentially get to the same starting point I had, so here's how you handle. The video frame is 960x720, but its correct aspect ratio should be 16:9, 1280x720. This approach, however, will work for any dimensions provided you know the correct output size.

Starting point is the original image:

[image]

Resize by checking "resample" and *unchecking* the aspect ratio lock:

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Now you can drop the image into an InDesign layout, assemble into a PDF with the Bridge Output module or directly from within Acrobat, etc.